# Crontab job is not running for concrete values; but executes for relative time values

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, cron

I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.0.4 and I am trying to setup a non-system cron job.
I used the "sudo crontab -e" command and this is how the file looks:

```
0 5 * * * root /home/jacob/rolllogsweb.sh
```

I want the script in that user's directory to run everyday at 5am.  It doesn't run at all.

However, if I modify the crontab -e entry to something like this, it does run:

```
*/5 * * * * root /home/jacob/rolllogsweb.sh
```

This basically tells it to run "Every 5 minutes" and that works.

Why will the first one not work?  I can't figure it out - the syntax looks right per the documentation.

Thank you,

Comment: What is the `root` command supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "root" from your crontab file:

0 5 * * * /home/jacob/rolllogsweb.sh

After the scheduler data you should put your command, not a user the command should run as (I assume this is what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: There is no file called "/var/log/cron" on the system.  Another interesting note is that when I exit the crontab -e, it saves the file under this location:  File Name to Write: /tmp/crontab.wxM64S/crontab

Comment: That is a tmp file cron uses when you are editing the job list. What do you see when you run crontab -l ?

Comment: When I run "sudo crontab -l" I see the output of the "crontab -e" file, which includes the job noted above in addition to all the default comments in the file.

Comment: Is cron logging enabled? Can you check in /etc/syslog.conf or /etc/rsyslog.conf if there's an entry for cron? and is crond running?

Comment: Running a "ps -ef |grep cron"  shows the following:  root     30399     1  0 Jun14 ?        00:00:00 cron.  So yes looks like it is running.  Like I said the job works fine when it's set to run every 5 minutes, but the one with an absolute time (run everyday at 5am) does not, even though its the same exact referenced script.  I do not have a "/etc/syslog.conf" on the system.  When I grepped the "/etc/rsyslog.conf" for "cron", it showed nothing.

Comment: yes, I'm asking some obvious questions just to see if something obvious comes up as I'm not sure what the problem is :). Can you add the following to rsyslog.conf, restart syslogd and schedule a cron job to start soon? 
cron.*  -/var/log/cron

Comment: Is the character between the entry fields space? Maybe you misplaced a tab?

Comment: Nimeshjm - I tried all of those steps and after analyzing the /var/log/cron it does in fact confirm that the cron job ran.  The weird thing is that the shell script that it runs only seems to execute if a command shell is open while the cron job is running - if no command shell is running, even though the cron job says it ran - the outputs of the shell script are not made.....

Comment: Can you post your script in pastebin? We've established cron is running and firing the job so it must be something in your script.

Comment: Does the user you are editing the crontab file for have permissions in those directories?

Comment: Nimeshjm - well I run the crontab command as follows:  "sudo crontab -e"; so it runs as root which does have permissions.  When I run the script independently of the cron job, I run it as such:  sudo ./rolllogsweb.sh and it runs successfully for that case....